# Is it possible to create an artificial model in FactoryBoy?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-unittest, factory-boy

I wanted to know if in the tests it is possible to somehow create an "artificial" model using FactoryBoy without touching models.py

I mean a simple model such as:

```
class SomeMod(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for the attribute `abstract` in the `Meta` options of the `factory` class, which is mentioned [here](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#factory.FactoryOptions.abstract) in Factory Boy documentation.

```py
from factory.django import DjangoModelFactory
from factory import Faker

class MyAbstractFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    title = Faker("last_name") # could be "company" or whatever you want to mock
    description = Faker("paragraph")

    class Meta:
         abstract = True
```

Is this what you're looking for? If not, please elaborate your question.